# Переменные в react.js

Tags: reactjs

Если я объявляю переменную с маленькой буквы, то код не работает (не выводит ничего в браузер и не выдает ошибку). Но если я меняю первую букву на заглавную, то все работает как часы. Объясните почему так, ведь в документации написано что можно переменные создавать и с маленькой буквы.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='content'></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var Hello = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
                );
            }
        });
ReactDOM.render(
        <Hello />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: может быть такая переменная уже есть с маленькой буквы уже где-то и ты или не помнишь или не знаешь... проверь ctrl+f

Comment: Это весь код! Больше переменных нет! Скопируйте этот код и запустите.

Comment: потому что это у тебя не просто переменная, а класс.. а класс в js  с большой буквы начинаются

Comment: Разобрался! Всем спасибо!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html это соглашение реакта. JS не имеет ничего против классов с маленькой буквы